# MySQL update with nested select

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with following structure.

```
Accounts (acc_id, name, balance)
GeneralLedger GL (account_id, voucher_id, debit,credit)
```

I want to update accounts balance in accounts table by calculating total debit and total credit from general ledger table.

i tried below query but its not working, has no error but does not update any record

```
UPDATE accounts a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT gl.account_id, SUM(gl.debit) total_debit, SUM(gl.credit) total_credit
  FROM general_ledger gl
  WHERE gl.voucher_id=1
  GROUP BY  gl.account_id
) gl ON gl.account_id=a.account_id

SET a.balance = a.balance + (total_credit-total_debit)
WHERE a.acc_id=gl.account_id
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get a syntax error or does it not give an expected result?

Comment: Don't think you need that last WHERE clause as the link is already defined in the sub-select.

Comment: @P.Salmon,  query is ok with 0 errors, but it does not update any record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query "works" but if the balance starts as null then adding to null results in null, you could catch this by using coalesce in your set statement or default it to 0 in your table definition. Also there is no such field as a.account_id so you should change this to a.acc_id.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Accounts, generalledger ;

create table accounts(acc_id int, name varchar(3), balance int);
create table generalledger(account_id int, voucher_id int, debit int,credit int);

insert into accounts values (1,'aaa',null),(2,'bbb',100);

insert into generalledger values
(1,1,10,null),(1,1,null,20),
(2,1,10,null),(2,1,null,10);

UPDATE accounts a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT gl.account_id, SUM(gl.debit) total_debit, SUM(gl.credit) total_credit
  FROM generalledger gl
  WHERE gl.voucher_id=1
  GROUP BY  gl.account_id
) gl ON gl.account_id=a.acc_id

SET a.balance = coalesce(a.balance,0) + (total_credit-total_debit)
;
select * from accounts; 

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from accounts;
+--------+------+---------+
| acc_id | name | balance |
+--------+------+---------+
|      1 | aaa  |      10 |
|      2 | bbb  |     100 |
+--------+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```